# Websphere: Declare VirtualHost in EAR instead of war

Tags: ear, websphere-8

I have an ear set up like this

```
EAR
  META-INF
    application.xml
  WAR1.war
  WAR2.war
```

The wars are preconstructed so I can't edit the web.xml or add and ibm-web-bnd.xml. Is there another way I can declare the Virtual Host?

Comment: A war file is a jar file is a zip file. You can modify the web.xml inside the war before putting it into your ear.

Comment: Right I agree but I would like to avoid it if possible because then I am modifying a vendor's code.

Comment: And you don't want to map the host at deploy time?